# How to get the ng-model of a select element while iterating it in a row of a table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Conside the snippet:

```
    var rows = [ '1', '2', '3', '4'];
    // HTML table
    <tr data-ng-repeat="record in rows()">
     <td>
        <select data-ng-model="dynamicInsurance[record]" 
                data-ng-options="dyn for dyn in onetwothreefour"
        </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
```

So there will be 4 rows with each having a select element.
And let's say I have selected different value from each of these drop downs.
Suppose in the dropdown, the following set of values is reflected-

```
one
two
three
four
```

& say,

```
from dropdown first  I select one
from dropdown second I select two
from dropdown third  I select three
from dropdown fourth I select four
```

On browser console, when I do

`$scope.dynamicInsurance[1]`

I get **one**

So I thought the whole set of values will be available in

```
$scope.dynamicInsurance
```

But `$scope.dynamicInsurance` gave me

```
Object : { 1 : "one" }
```

instead.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the whole set of values `(i.e one, two, three, four)` from all the dropdowns?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller first define `$scope.dynamicInsurance` to be an array like this,

```
$scope.dynamicInsurance=[];
```

Comment: It works but only after I have done INSPECT element on one of the dropdowns.Before this action, $scope.dynamicInsurance is undefined & AFTER the inspect element on one of the drop downs, the array gets filled. Why? It need to get filled before I do inspect element.

Comment: One more thing, the html is part of the GetTemplate() in a directive. I have defined `scope.dynamicInsurance = [];` inside the link function.